# Intent filter not working properly

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent, webview, intentfilter

The URL redirects to another URL which in turn is supposed to redirect back to my app, but it doesn't. Am I missing something here?

Actual redirect URL is: `https://mpivchev.github.io/Reddit-App/redirect?state=XXXXXX&code=XXXXXX`

Intent filter:

```
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:host="mpivchev.github.io"
            android:scheme="https"
            android:path="/Reddit-App/redirect" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

WebView stays on the redirect page instead of returning back to the app:

[image]

Comment: try changing android:path to android:pathPrefix

Comment: @Arshad Same thing

Comment: your code looks fine. Can you try changing your data to something else other than normal URL, something like this
<data android:host="myhost"
            android:scheme="myscheme"
            android:path="/redirect" />
As I have similar code and it works fine for me, the only difference I have in my code is i dnt use normal URL, I have a customized scheme and host for data

Comment: @Arshad But if the real redirect URL is not the same as the redirect URL provided in the intent filter, how is it going to work?

Comment: I mean to say, try changing the format and then use the new formatted URL not your original url just to cross check whether its the code issue or URL issue. So after customizing your URL will be myhost://myscheme/redirect try opening this in your mobile browser this should open your app. This is just to cross check

Comment: @Arshad So I changed the scheme to "html" and the host to "example.com" and removed the path cuz there isn't any. I tried to open the site in the browser but the app didn't run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158775/discussion-between-milen-and-arshad).